# PyViennaCL installation using pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, viennacl

I am trying to install PyViennaCL (https://github.com/viennacl/pyviennacl-dev) on Windows 10 64-bit and I am using Python 3.9.6.
Using `pip install pyviennacl`, the error I received at first was that Visual C++ needed is version 14.0 or higher, I solved this issue by downloading vs buildtools. Now, I receive this error in the pip log.

```
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170 Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170   File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170     success = install_legacy(
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170   File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\legacy.py", line 114, in install
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170     raise LegacyInstallFailure from e
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170 pip._internal.operations.install.legacy.LegacyInstallFailure
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170 
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170 
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170 Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170   File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 164, in exc_logging_wrapper
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170     status = run_func(*args)
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170   File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 204, in wrapper
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170     return func(self, options, args)
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170   File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 404, in run
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170     installed = install_given_reqs(
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170   File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 73, in install_given_reqs
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170     requirement.install(
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170   File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 869, in install
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170     raise exc.__cause__
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170   File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\legacy.py", line 102, in install
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170     runner(
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170   File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\subprocess.py", line 282, in runner
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170     call_subprocess(
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170   File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\subprocess.py", line 254, in call_subprocess
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170     raise InstallationSubprocessError(proc.returncode, command_desc)
2021-10-13T19:11:20,170 pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationSubprocessError: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gpf662wg\\pyviennacl_a4fbf7b27c6d4354baba43864f9475fd\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gpf662wg\\pyviennacl_a4fbf7b27c6d4354baba43864f9475fd\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8qjep_77\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include\pyviennacl' Check the logs for full command output.
2021-10-13T19:11:20,225 Removed build tracker: 'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-3_czkvw8'
```

Comment: Is that the complete error message? If not, can you add the rest?

Comment: I think the error message is too long to include. I can email the log file though.

Comment: Post it on hastebin or another paste site.

Comment: Try to pass `-q` to your pip call. That should result in a much shorter log

Comment: https://pastebin.com/F97FK5fH. This is the output with the `-q` option in pip. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [website](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwim7cmS7svzAhWQnxQKHd8wAAMQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lfd.uci.edu%2F%7Egohlke%2Fpythonlibs%2F&usg=AOvVaw360rTn3aWaaz8cfdxdPvJP) named Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages which collects a variety of useful python libraries in the binary form. If you are going to use the library **AS IS** (not going to change or develop) I suggest download the proper version of the `.whl` file (according to windows version, python interpreter version and ...) then install it locally instead of the complex procedure of building binary file. Fortunately, there are several versions of `pyviennacl` [there](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyviennacl)!

```
#download proper version 
pip install /path/to/your/downloaded/file.whl
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I was using a newer version of python (the package needed python 3.6). So, I downloaded py 3.6  and its pip version and I was able to install the library successfully.