# Will Numpy wheels for python 3.10 32 bits be available

Tags: numpy

First I asked on gitter, though I got help they were not sure, see [link](https://gitter.im/numpy/numpy?at=6177f8efcd4972068b6d58e6)

Numpy release v1.21.3 states:

> Note a few oddities about Python 3.10:
>
> - There are no 32 bit wheels for Windows, Mac, or Linux.

Questions:

- Those wheels were not provided this time, does someone know, why?
- From the release notes is not clear to me if wheels for windows 32 bits will be provided in the future or from now own there will be no 32 bits wheels
- Which options do we have now? Build it on our own or download from [gohlke/pythonlibs](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) he seems to have built numpy wheels for py3.10 but `pip download/install` is honestly much more convenient.

Background: we test a 32bit dll with cffi and numpy and we would like to upgrade.

Comment: Have you tried asking this the maintainers of that package?

Comment: Did you see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69559936/pyviennacl-installation-using-pip/69581218#69581218)?

Comment: Simply don't upgrade. The last Intel CPU that only supported 32bit was released almost 20 years ago. So you're testing for an ancient architecture that you will eventually phase out anyways.

Comment: Question 1: see first link I posted
Question 2: see second link I posted, the post you liked refers to the same page I mentioned (gohlke)
Question 3: Not upgrading has also it's maintance cost. I should have given more context, the situation is a bit more complex than that. On PC that's right. The problem is that we test a 32 bit dll on PC, the code under test will eventually run on a embedded device which is a 32 bit architecture, do you have a feeling when we will have no more embedded devices on 32bit arch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numpy-1.22.3-cp310-cp310-win32.whl is now available on pypi, just `pip install numpy` on python-3.10 32 bit and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the GitHub actions infrastructure repo dropped 32bit a while back and nobody complained: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/4226#issuecomment-945097662

Comment: That issue is now solved